# вызываю функцию генератор и возвращается не то что надо

Tags: python, классы, генераторы

вот мой код

```
 class Ad():
    array_ad=[]

    def get_ad(self):#показывает обьявление
        txt=self.user_name+'\n'+'\n'+self.text_ad
        return( txt)


    @staticmethod
    def next_ad():
        i=0
        while  True:
            if Ad.i<len(Ad.array_ad):
                t=Ad.array_ad[Ad.i].get_ad()
                Ad.i+=1
                yield t
            else:
                yield 'end'
```

при запуске выдает <generator object Ad.next_ad at 0x0000022FFF556648>

Comment: Судя по всему, код выдает то, что вы ему сказали. Как вы его "запускаете"?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, это то, что Вам надо

```
class Ad():
    array_ad=['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
    i = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_name = 'handowl'
        self.text_ad = 'ad text'
    
    def get_ad(self):#показывает обьявление
        txt = self.user_name+'\n'+'\n'+self.text_ad
        return (txt)


    @staticmethod
    def next_ad():
        while Ad.i < len(Ad.array_ad):
            t = Ad.array_ad[Ad.i]
            Ad.i += 1
            yield t
        yield 'end'

a = Ad()            
for i in a.next_ad():
    print(i)
```

Comment: Очевидно, что без метода `__init__` можно обойтись. Не понятна задача, но здесь что-то работает, вроде отдается какой-то текст, по генератору